# How to proxy a web service on mule 3.7.0 CE

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, mule

I was using mule 3.4.0 CE to proxy a remote web service, but with the new 3.7.0 CE i cant find any example of this working over flow so i can use http shared connector, any clue?

Example that does not work for C# based consumers:

```
<flow name="Test">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/services/teste/teste" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="AutenticacaoServicoFlowTesteHttp - #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <response>
        <logger message="ATestHttp - response - #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </response>
    <set-variable variableName="queryStringIncompleto" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'host']/logTicket?ipFrom=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.remote.address']&amp;requestSize=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri'.length()]&amp;url=#[message.inboundProperties.'host']#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri'.replaceAll(&quot;&amp;&quot;, &quot;%26&quot;)]&amp;userName=#[message.inboundProperties.'authorization']&amp;modifiedRequestSize=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri'.length()]" doc:name="QueryString LogTicket"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri' == '/services/Autentic?wsdl']">
            <set-variable variableName="queryString" value="#[flowVars.queryStringIncompleto]&amp;method=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.method']" doc:name="QueryString LogBilhetagem"/>
            <cxf:proxy-service  namespace="logTeste.gov" service="AutenticacaoServico" payload="envelope" wsdlLocation="${targetServerLog}/servicos/v2/Autentic.svc?singleWsdl" soapVersion="1.2" doc:name="CXF"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-variable variableName="queryString" value="#[flowVars.queryStringIncompleto]&amp;method=#[message.inboundProperties.'SOAPAction'.replaceAll(&quot;\&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;)]" doc:name="QueryString LogTicket"/>
            <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
                <add-message-property key="SOAPAction" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'SOAPAction']"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>
            <outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="${targetServerLog}/servicos/v2/Autentc.svc" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="Generic"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <set-variable variableName="payloadLog" value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Guarda Payload Log"/>
    <outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="https://teste:teste@#[flowVars.queryString]" doc:name="Log Bilhetagem"/>
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars.payloadLog]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <response>
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
    </response>
</flow>
```

On most C# applications that consume this WS will do a first connection OK and the seccond will do a timeout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the problem and solved, wasnt the implementation, what i do is redirect a WS to the correct place but i also log the message into another WS, that will hang the flow and will not be possible to do a cascade call to alot of methods.
So i just took out the seccond outbound to log the message and i will use another approach to log the message.

Code:

```
<flow name="Test">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/services/teste/teste" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<set-variable variableName="queryStringIncompleto" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'host']/logTicket?ipFrom=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.remote.address']&amp;requestSize=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri'.length()]&amp;url=#[message.inboundProperties.'host']#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri'.replaceAll(&quot;&amp;&quot;, &quot;%26&quot;)]&amp;userName=#[message.inboundProperties.'authorization']&amp;modifiedRequestSize=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri'.length()]" doc:name="QueryString LogTicket"/>
<choice doc:name="Choice">
    <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri' == '/services/Autentic?wsdl']">
        <set-variable variableName="queryString" value="#[flowVars.queryStringIncompleto]&amp;method=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.method']" doc:name="QueryString LogBilhetagem"/>
        <cxf:proxy-service  namespace="logTeste.gov" service="AutenticacaoServico" payload="envelope" wsdlLocation="${targetServerLog}/servicos/v2/Autentic.svc?singleWsdl" soapVersion="1.2" doc:name="CXF"/>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <set-variable variableName="queryString" value="#[flowVars.queryStringIncompleto]&amp;method=#[message.inboundProperties.'SOAPAction'.replaceAll(&quot;\&quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;)]" doc:name="QueryString LogTicket"/>
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="SOAPAction" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'SOAPAction']"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="${targetServerLog}/servicos/v2/Autentc.svc" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="Generic"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
<response>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
        <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're trying to proxy the services would not be the Ideal way of doing it, also was not the ideal in 3.4, please see the following documentation pages:

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Proxying+Web+Services+with+CXF
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Web+Service+Proxy+Pattern

These are two standard way of proxying webservices.

Comment: i did an implementation using pattern:web-service-proxy  but it doesnt not allow me to use shared connector and the cxf implementation i have hangs on MS consumers, so i dont know what to do...

Comment: What I normally do is enable http wire-logs and compare the difference between the call that mule makes and a direct call that works, for MS-based webservices normally the http headers are the issue.

Comment: Ok, i did with pattern but i cant use shared resource port with that, any clue on how to do it?

Comment: If you have a global http or https connector in your domain, then the proxy-pattern will use that, otherwise you can simply use the connector-ref attribute to refer to a shared resources connector.